# OLS Prediction Error of sum of m future observations

Tags: least-squares, prediction-interval

A paper I'm reading states the "The prediction error of a sum of m future observations (as is needed for determining energy savings) is given by Theil (1971)"

[image]

Due to covid I don't have access to the library. In this equation can someone advise if the X are augmented to include a column of 1 for the regression constant, or does the addition of I account for the constant (i.e. assuming the model is $y = a_0 + a_1 x$)?

Thiel, H. 1971. Principles of Econometrics. John Wiley & Sons, New York.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both $X$ and $X_{\text{post}}$ need to include the constant.

The $\mathbf{1}'$ and $\mathbf{1}$ are there because we are summing the predictions, so we are summing their variances and covariances. The $+I$ is because it's a prediction interval -- so you need to include the process variance; there's a common factor of $\sigma^2$ in both terms -- which we estimate by MSE -- that is pulled outside the brackets, $[.]$.